# Survey123 Connect geolocate from a text field using online survey

Tags: arcgis-online, excel, reverse-geocoding, arcgis-survey123

From the web survey, is it possible to put a point on the map from typing in your address? As it stands, when I type my address a drop down from the search bar in the map appears. But, the map doesn't zoom to my address.

[image]

Here's is my XLSX form:

[image]

From what I understand from [this blog](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/understanding-reverse-geocoding-in-survey123-3-0/ba-p/891644), I'm supposed to pull coordinates from the geopoint field, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. `pulldata("@geopoint",${locate},"reversegeocode.address.Match_addr")`

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000019081

Comment: Do you know of an example? That support doc is pretty vague. I've had a look here: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-reverse-geocode.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_ECC8B7DD83034CB2A1126523983616C4. But, this does the opposite of what I want. I want to type an address and have a point appear on the map.